# Python Type Error

Tags: python

hey so i've been getting a type error that says 
"traceback (most recent call last):
File "(stdin)", line 1 in, (module)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'

The entire code is:

```
    # 1 - Import library
    ... import.pygame
    from pygame.locals import *
    # 2 - Initialize the game
    ... pygame.init() 
    (6, 0)
    "width", "height" - 640, 480
```

then the error message occurs after that 
please help me to fix it because i'm clueless.

Comment: What do you expect `"height" - 640` to do?

Comment: The line `"width", "height" - 640, 480` is telling. You cannot subtract an int from a string. Perhaps you mean `("width", "height", "-", "640", "480")` -- i.e., all strings.

Comment: @Blender i don't know probably adjust the height to 640? i'm clueless right now man :|

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but I can not identify a working code and therefore analyze the error in total, so I am just referencing a tutorial example now.

In my opinion, you are not defining width and height as they should be defined (should be defined for/as resolution.

See a simple example here:
http://jonasbsb.jo.funpic.de/hendrix/pygame-example.html

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The error is definitely due to `"height" - 640` because you can't subtract an integer from a strong.

I would guess that the minus sign is a typo, and that the line should actually read

```
width, height = 640, 480   # VGA screen resolution
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Do this :

```
import pygame 

from pygame.locals import * 

pygame.init()

width , height = 640,480
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).